# How can I get the list of microphones on android Api 17 (usb connected mic's)

Tags: android, audio, microphone, audiorecord, audio-device

For Android Api level 23, you can use `AudioRecord.setPreferredDevice();`

And you can also use:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    AudioDeviceInfo[] adi = audioManager.getDevices(AudioManager.GET_DEVICES_OUTPUTS);
}
```

But is it possible to get a list of your microphones, on a API level lower than 23? (I need it for 17).

Comment: did you find answer for this??

Comment: No. not lower than 23